# Does sequentially closedness of sequential closure imply closedness?

Tags: general-topology

I follow the notation in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space) article on sequential spaces.
Let $X$ be a topological space, $A \subseteq X$ and consider the sequential closure $[A]_{\text{seq}}$ which is in general not sequentially closed, i.e. $[A]_{\text{seq}} \subsetneq [[A]_{\text{seq}}]_{\text{seq}}$ (and thus not closed).

Assume that the sequential closure of every subset $A$ of $X$ is sequentially closed. Does it then follow that $X$ is sequential, i.e. $[A]_{\text{seq}} = \overline{A}$ for every $A \subseteq X$ (and thus Fréchet-Urysohn)?

Formulated equivalently: If the transfinite sequential closure stops at $\alpha = 1$ for every subset $A$ of $X$ does it then follow that $\alpha = 1$ is the sequential order of $X$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the co-countable topology on the reals, there are no non-trivial convergent sequences. So there $[A]_{\mbox{seq}} = A$ for all $A$. But $A$ is non-sequential, as all uncountable subsets are dense.

Normally one defines the "sequential closure" as the transfinite closure of your $[A]_{\text{seq}}$ operation, also denoted $\operatorname{scl}(A)$ or variations thereof (or $[A]_{\text{seq}}$ is denoted scl, and its closure with an extra *). This is by construction a sequentially closed set, the smallest one that contains $A$, and has a better claim to being the sequential closure in name.

If $\operatorname{scl}(A) = \overline{A}$ for all $A$, the space is called a sequential space. If however $[A]_{\text{seq}} = \operatorname{scl}(A) = \overline{A}$, a space is called Fréchet-Urysohn. This holds for all first countable spaces, e.g.

Comment: Thanks. Here is a further reference: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/170335/sequential-closure-of-a-set-standard-terminology-notation-and-properties